# how can I extract JPEG from MJPEG over HTTP? C#

Tags: c#, stream, ip-camera, motion, mjpeg

I have a `IP CAMERA` which it is a `Raspberry PI` with `Motion` installed. I want to get one frame when an event is triggered using `C#`. The programming code in C# is as follows:

```
string sourceURL = "http://192.168.1.12:8081";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pass");

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
using (Stream output = File.Create("some_image.jpeg"))
using (Stream input = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    input.CopyTo(output); //<-- the code stops here 
}
```

Please, does anybody have an idea?

Comment: _"In response to a GET request for a MJPEG file or stream, the server streams the sequence of JPEG frames over HTTP. A special mime-type content type multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=<boundary-name> informs the client to expect several parts (frames) as an answer delimited by <boundary-name>. This boundary name is expressly disclosed within the MIME-type declaration itself."_ (yeah, I know, Wikipedia...) => Try and find out what the boundary is, cut the jpeg out of the stream using that boundary.

Comment: But if I remember correctly, there should also be an endpoint for requesting a still image ...

Comment: why don't u just save the file in memory and then convert it?

Comment: see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28234/take-snap-from-raspberry-pi-using-motion for action/snapshot